# what is a tight lower bound on the coupon collector time?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In the classic [Coupon Collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), it is well known that the time $T$ necessary to complete a set of $n$ randomly-picked coupons satisfies $E[T] \sim n \ln n $,$Var(T) \sim n^2$, and $\Pr(T > n \ln n + cn) < e^{-c}$.

This upper bound is better than the one given by the Chebyshev inequality, which would be roughly  $1/c^2$.

My question is: is there a corresponding better-than-Chebyshev *lower bound* for $T$? (e.g., something like $\Pr(T < n \ln n - cn) < e^{-c}$ ) ?

Comment: David, this might be an appropriate question for Math Overflow.  If you don't get an answer here in a day or two, you might want to try there.

Comment: also asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7774/what-is-a-tight-lower-bound-on-the-coupon-collector-time and discussed at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/what-is-the-proper-way-to-acknowledge-an-answer-posted-on-another-forum-site

Answer (score 2):

The question was asked and answered at stats.SE: see  https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7774/. I am posting this just so that the question does not remain unanswered.